# Exaggerated use of functions in Python?

Tags: python

I am currently reading [this](http://inventwithpython.com/index.html) book on Python and one thing I've noticed is that it takes functional programming rather seriously. I mean, if you take a look for example, at [this](http://inventwithpython.com/chapter14.html) chapter's source code, looking at lines 14-16 you see that the writer used a function just to get some input, instead of having it somewhere around line 53.
I just don't understand what's the point of abusing functions so much, and I wanted to know what does Python's ideology say about this matter, about functional programming.

Comment: That's not what [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) means.

Comment: @sepp2k Thanks... I don't know why I mixed this up like that, but thanks for making it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally considered good style to write small functions which do a single thing.

This has four main advantages:

- it helps write 'self-documenting code' (eg `message = get_message()` is incredilby clear)
- it makes your code significantly easier to debug and to test
- it promotes code reuse (what if you want to get a message from multiple places in your code?)
- it allows you to later add to or change the functionality of small snippets of code easily (eg, what if you later want to get a message over the network?)

---

As sepp2k points out in a comment, this is definitely not 'functional programming'; it's simply good style in a procedural language.

I agree that this can sometimes look contrived in simple examples, like the ones you linked to, but it's a very good practice to get into.  Failing to break things up in large programs can make your code really hard to maintain.

(As an aside, it's a good idea to follow [the PEP8 style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which suggests that function names `should_use_underscores()`).